# Restream Video with Wowza

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, wowza

Application publishes video stream to Wowza. Then Wowza pushes that stream to FMS server.
I can setup restreaming manually via Stream -> Stream Targets -> New Target.
Also I found that it is possible with REST API( https://www.wowza.com/docs/stream-targets-query-examples-push-publishing ).

But I actually want to do it completely automatically.
Is it possible? Maybe Wowza have some triggers on stream broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking into a REST API solution, one way to make this completely automated is when you publish your stream, trigger a script that queries the stream name via REST API, saves the stream name to a variable, and adds it as a Stream Target via REST API.

Comment: i want to allow users post streams via GoCoder, but i don't want to allow them to call wowza rest  api. I'm not limited with rest api, any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Wowza has the pushpublish packages that you can leverage in a custom Java module that would create a stream target for all published streams. This might be better for your workflow then. You can find information for these packages in the serverapi documentation.